# Windows 7 goes silent out of nowhere

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, performance

I have a very annoying and weird problem. During run-time my sound disappears but the volume control shows that something is playing. I can't hear anything though.
I noticed that all my media players will play back but the timer runs really slow.  Additionally, when I drag any window that overlaps one of my media players, the trace of this window is shown (like the dragging is really lagging).

Just to make things shorter, here is what I have already tried:

- I ran the troubleshooter
- I restarted the Windows Audio service
- I updated my sound card driver
- I un-installed and re-installed my soundcard
- I disabled and enabled my audio playback device
- I tried plugging in different headphones into front/rear-output jack

Nothing of the above worked.  It can't be hardware related since I also run Ubuntu on the same system and everything is working fine there.  The sound comes back after I restart Windows. It disappears at random points while using it.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Update your video drivers, because the window-dragging thing doesn't sound like an audio driver problem to me. Further, check the system event log for errors.

Comment: Anecdote: A same behavior starte happening to a Win 7 64 bit system of mine. The culprit was most likely an update I did to the RealTek driver via Windows Update. (I think this was one of the optional update, but I installed it anyway). I rolled back the update via System Restore and the issue no longer reproduces.

Comment: The "window dragging" likely means nothing. The media player applications depend on the audio stream to provide timing for the video, so if those system calls are wonky because of audio problems, that could interfere with the video refresh. Or something like that.